# Как передать путь к каталогу?

Tags: php

Мне нужно получить список папок в каталоге, где запускается url ярлык со ссылкой на скрипт сервера.

К примеру, есть несколько папок на сетевом диске

```
/share/folder1/
/share/folder2/
```

и т.д.
В каждой папке лежит url ярлык со ссылкой на скрипт на сервере
При запуске ярлыка мне необходимо проводить некоторые действия со списком папок внутри folder1 и folder2.

Как получать путь к этим каталогам на сервере?

Comment: Приведите код файла из папок /folder1 и /folder2, в них есть обработка PHP?

Comment: @Vladimir в них нет обработки, в папках содержатся просто ярлыки c URL на серверный скрипт, я планировал что средствами php можно получить путь под которым запускаются эти ярлыки, но теперь уже сомневаюсь что так можно

Comment: Путь к скрипту можно узнать директивой dirname(_ _ FILE _ _) - в файле который выполняет скрипт. Если вам требуется знать с какого именно URL был редирект то для этого нужно знать содержимое ваших файлов и уже исходя из их содержимого определяет URL и передавать его вашему скрипту.

Comment: @Vladimir, используя dirname(_ _ FILE _ _)  я получаю имя текущего скрипта, относительно каталога на севере, где располагается сам скрипт, я же хочу получить имя директории где запускается файл клиента, а именно /share/folder1 + список папок которые тут находятся.

Comment: "В каждой папке лежит url ярлык со ссылкой на скрипт на сервере" как реализована данная ссылка? Приведите больше конкретного кода а не общего описания.